# How can I customize lombok SuperBuilder's build method?

Tags: java, lombok, builder

I want to execute some method after lombok `builder().build();`.

But I don't want to execute it manually like `builder().build().someMethod();`

`@SuperBuilder`'s `build()` was different from `@Builder`.

How can I customize it?

```
@SuperBuilder(buildMethodName = "defaultBuild")
class Foo {
    
    ...

    public static class FooBuilder {
        public FooBuilder build() {
            return defaultBuild().someMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

It works in `@Builder` but not in `@SuperBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the cavalcade of generics and other trickery to make `@SuperBuilder` work, you can't just write it yourself. `@SuperBuilder` is more picky, in other words (`@Builder` will let you write various things yourself, SuperBuilder does not). For example, your `FooBuilder` class needs a bevy of generics. Instead of forcing you to read a lot of documentation, or delomboking to know what it should look like, SuperBuilder just doesn't let you, instead.

Comment: In fact you _can_ customize the `build` method since a few releases. It's just not simple, as you have to delombok and copy the builder and method headers from there. So my advice is: don't do it unless you really know what you are doing.